# Firestore how to disable automatic sync with cloud database?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I noticed this behavior:

1. Disconnect a device from the internet
2. Create a few new documents while still offline
3. Close the app Then
4. Go online and reopen App
5. Documents are automatically synced with firestore (I lose control over completeListener)

Problem is that actions I had in onCompleteListener are not run.
Like in this snippet *(do some super important stuff)* is not run in the described scenario, also OnFailureListener is not called when a user is offline, so I cannot tell if it went ok or not.

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(...).collection(...)
                    .set(message).addOnCompleteListener {
                     //do some super important stuff
                   }
```

I would rather do sync *in this case* on my own so I want it to fail and not repeat again.

**How can I disable automatic sync of firestore?, for this one case only**

Answer (score 2):

So I wanted to ask this question and somehow Firestore transactions got to me.
So to fix this problem I used transactions ([firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) / [realtime dbs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions))

> Transactions will fail when the client is offline.

So how it works now.

I try to run the transaction. 
**A** If it fails I store it into a database
**B** If it succeeds I try to remove it from the database
 And on every app start, I run sync service (check unsynced dbs and insert missing)

```
val OBJECT = ...
val ref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(...).collection(...)

FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().runTransaction(
        object : Transaction.Function<Boolean> {

            override fun apply(transaction: Transaction): Boolean? {
                transaction.set(ref, OBJECT)
                transaction.update(ref, PROPERTY, VALUE)
                return true
            }
        })
          .addOnSuccessListener {
               println("Inserting $OBJECT ended with success==$it")
               //todo remove from dbs (unsynced messages)

          }.addOnFailureListener {
               it.printStackTrace()
               //todo save to dbs (unsynced messages)
                }
```

*//They work similarly in realtime database*